# Error on Craft 3 install

Tags: craft3, installation

When attempting to install Craft 3 in OSX El Cap, I'm getting the following errors:

> Script @php craft setup/welcome handling the post-create-project-cmd event returned with error code 255
>   /Craft3/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php on line 104
>
> Parse error: parse error in PATH/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php on line 104
>   Script @php craft setup/welcome handling the post-create-project-cmd event returned with error code 255

I used the `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag as I am using PHP7 on MAMP.

When I attempt to load index.php in the browser I'm seeing this seemingly related issue in the trace:

> in PATH/web/index.php at line 21 – yii\base\Application::run() 15161718192021    (new Dotenv\Dotenv(CRAFT_BASE_PATH))->load();}
>
> // Load and run Craft
>   define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', getenv('ENVIRONMENT') ?: 'production');
>   $app = require CRAFT_VENDOR_PATH.'/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php';
>   $app->run();

I've substituted "PATH" in all errors in lieu of the actual path.

Any advice on resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your executing the default PHP 5.x PHP install instead of MAMP's PHP 7.  What if you run `/path/to/MAMP/PHP7/php /path/to/composer.phar create-project...`?

Comment: I was able to get a clean install and ran the setup in the CLI. I can now get to the CP login but nothing happens when I attempt to login. No error.

Comment: Started over at the top of the install and all is now working as expected. Thanks for your. help.

Comment: Glad you're all sorted... would you mind piecing together an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to install under MAMP with PHP7 we added the MAMP PHP7 path with the following command:

> export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.15/bin:$PATH"

After achieving a successful Craft 3 install we ran the setup in the CLI and we also created a fresh DB and a new MAMP host following the sequence recommended in the installation docs.

Comment: Note that you need to swap out `php7.0.15` out for the exact version you are using. Just navigate to the directory in finder to double check.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145667/how-to-override-the-path-of-php-to-use-the-mamp-path) you can add

```
# Use MAMP version of PHP
PHP_VERSION=`ls /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/ | sort -n | tail -1`
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/${PHP_VERSION}/bin:$PATH
```

to `.bash_profile`.

This grabs your current php Version in MAMP and you can install it without setting `--ignore-platform-reqs`.