# Craft 3 via composer with Mamp Pro

Tags: craft3, install, installation, composer

Is it possible to get an idiots guide to this:

[Error on Craft 3 install](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/22445/error-on-craft-3-install)

I'm just not following the context of the answer/commands, a detailed step by step would be invaluable for fear of trying something, not really understanding what's going on and possibly doing it wrong and affecting dependent tech, just a thought, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[nystudio107](https://nystudio107.com) just released a nice guide yesterday for setting up a Craft 3 site via composer.  No mention of Mamp Pro, but I don't think that should really be a problem if you're already used to using it, as you would just make sure your hosts file is pointing to the `/web/index.php` file.  The article does a great job of explaining what a lot of the terminal commands actually refer to instead of just telling you what to type in.

https://nystudio107.com/blog/setting-up-a-craft-cms-3-project

Comment: Thanks. Wow that is a brilliant article! although I can't find a specific solution to the error I've encountered, its a great read and must have taken a lot of work to create such a concise article! Perhaps the question is should I use MAMP any more?

Comment: For the record, I have a Craft 3 dev site set up under Mamp Pro and it hasn't been a problem.

Comment: I can't figure how to stop getting the following error tho:
'Parse error: parse error in PATH/crafttest/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php on line 104
Script @php craft setup/welcome handling the post-create-project-cmd event returned with error code 255'

Comment: this apparently remedies the problem, but I don' understand how to apply it (at what stage of the commands)?

**In order to install under MAMP with PHP7 we added the MAMP PHP7 path with the following command:

export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.15/bin:$PATH" **

Comment: In case it helps for anyone without the error, this runs through Craft3 and Mamp Pro: https://mikateach.me/setting-craft-cms-3-with-xampp-or-mamp/ but assumes no unexpected error code 255

Comment: It might be worth checking out another article he wrote on [how to set up & use Homestead](https://nystudio107.com/blog/local-development-with-vagrant-homestead). It got a MAMP user like myself completely off of MAMP.

Comment: No reason that I can see to give up on MAMP with Craft 3. Working for me once I worked out the solution to this error (with guidance from Brad ; )

Answer (score 2):

Incase helps any other designer come devs who haven't a full grasp on dev/CL workflow, these steps worked for me – with thanks to craft support/community:

1. in terminal, run exactly this: `PATH="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.15/bin:$PATH"`
2. `composer create-project craftcms/craft PATH -s beta --ignore-platform-reqs`
   PATH being your absolute path to your project (I crudely type in terminal, 
   `cd` 
   then drag the folder into terminal to get that path).
   Note: I seem to have to go through #1 each time I install Craft3 via composer else I get an error.
   Note: in #1 the php version needs to match what you are using (needs to be 7+ I believe).

Comment: Note: Make sure to substitute into the above command the PHP version that MAMP is actually implementing. It may differ from 7.0.15. I'm also a bit mystified as to why I have to implement this command on every Craft 3 installation. Would think that adding the php version to the path would stick.